# Is there a way to resign first responder of view that isn't currently presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

This is the situation:

The root view controller of a `UINavigationController` has a search bar. When a user searches something, they can tap on a cell that pushes a new view controller onto the navigation controller with some info. When this happens, the intended behavior is for the user to be able to go back and still see the keyboard open with the most recent search query populated within the search bar.

However, there is also a situation in which the user may tap on a tab bar that should pop all the view controllers off the navigation controller *except* the root controller. In that case, I would like to resign the search bar `textField`'s first responder *before* the root controller is presented. If I try to do this in `viewWillAppear(_:)`, `resignFirstResponder()` fails.

Is this possible? I've tried using delegation and notifications but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this. If the VC with the search bar is being popped off anyway, why do you bother manually hiding the keyboard? Doesn't the keyboard disappear automatically when the VC is popped?

Comment: The search bar and keyboard exist on the root controller (which isn't being popped off).

Comment: Oh, so sometimes when you navigate back to root, you want to see the keyboard, and sometimes you don't?

Comment: Try `self.view.endEditing(true)` to hide the keyboard, where `self` is the root VC.

Comment: @Sweeper: I tried that but it didn't work... but I ended up figuring out a workaround. 

I created a separate `resignResponder` flag within the root VC and set it to false by default. When the tab is pressed, that flag is switched to true. Within the search bar's `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` delegate function, I put a guard statement at the start to make sure that `resignResponder` is off. If it's on, `textField.resignResponder()` is called within the else block. That does the trick. :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Sweeper said, `endEditing` worked for me, but `resignFirstResponder` didn't.  I executed in `viewWillAppear`:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button = UIButton()
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.tag = 1
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if case let tag = sender.tag, tag == 1 {
            let secondVC = SecondVC()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
}

let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navVC
```